# How to get second maximum salary from employee table

Tags: sql-server

```
select row_number()over( order by ID desc ),
       max(S) from EMPLOYEE group by ID order by ID DESC
```

OFFSET 2 ROWS

FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
with cte
as
(
select SeqNo = row_number()over( order by S desc ),* from EMPLOYEE
)
select * from cte where SeqNo = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
select empno
    from
        (
        select empno, rownum as rownum 
        from (
              select empno
              from emp group by id
              order by id desc
              )
        )
    where rownum=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

with offset and fetch

```
select id, max(S) from EMPLOYEE group by ID order by 2 DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```